# When a master at work / When a master is at work

Tags: expressions

How to say correctly:

> What the violin really sounds like when a master at work.

Or

> What the violin really sounds like when a master is at work.

Answer (score 1):

"What the violin really sounds like when a master is at work" is closer to being grammatically correct.  It is worth noting you have a sentence fragment, so it is possible the other option might work better in your case, but I cannot think of a sentence where that would be true.

Is there more to your thought?  That might help you get a more clear answer.